# Passing Values Java classes

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with values from firebase database and a simple textview where to show them.

```
public class FindReportActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    EditText editTextFindReport;
    TextView textViewCommento;
    TextView textViewGravita;
    ImageView imageViewFindReport;
    String cdt;
    Report report;
    ReportDAO reportDAO = new ReportDAO();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_report);
        imageViewFindReport = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewFindReport);
        editTextFindReport = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCDT);
        textViewCommento= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcommento);
        textViewGravita= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewgravita);

        imageViewFindReport.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( v == imageViewFindReport){

            cdt = editTextFindReport.getText().toString().trim();
            textViewCommento.setText(reportDAO.findReport(cdt));

        }
    }
}
```

here ReportDAO class

```
public class ReportDAO {
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    String commento = "non";

    public ReportDAO(){ }


    public String findReport(String cdt){

        DatabaseReference refReport = databaseReference.child("Report").child(cdt).child("commento");
        refReport.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                commento = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return commento;
    }
```

when i click the imageview, the frist time is blank, second time is correct value... why?

Comment: sorry, for test i've assigned "non" to commento, and frist time is "non", second time is correct

Comment: You're only setting a listener for `refReport`, but that doesn't mean the value is set instantly, so it's not available for you to return in the same method. I would suggest to try to understand the concept of a listener first, and then think about passing values to your view. For that look into MVP or MVVM architectural models, which define how the values should be passed. A great place to start is the new [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Comment: is not possible that my andorid studio work with API 27 ( Oreo) and i debug on my phone with Andorid 7.1?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. You normally have a target SDK as high as possible, but the apps of course run on older devices (given you don't use APIs added in newer android versions).

Comment: i'm stuck, how i can implement a listener for success on my refReport?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a listener that waits for the commento to get available, because the findReport method works asynchronous.

Comment: In reportDAO? Or in activity?